# Working principle of PCB

Tags: pcb

This PCB is to turn on and off an LED. The captive touchpad is to turn on and off the LED, and one side of this touchpad is connected to GND and the other side to Pin 2 of the IC. Pin 1 is connected to the LED, the other side of the LED is connected to VCC. Pin 3 of the IC is connected to VCC, Pin 4 is NC and Pin 5 is connected to GND. The other side of the PCB has no traces on it. I like to know how this circuit works so i can make my own version of it. Can someone explain how this PCB works and what component that is ? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I see one component on pcb, LED. Are you asking for which component?

Comment: I mean the sot23 package

Comment: The component is very likely a "generic micro controller". There's this channel on Youtube called BigClive and he regularly explains and reverse-engineers products like this. Here's one example you could have a look at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zSkyQQrAbBc

Comment: *The captive touchpad* - can you explain why you call it this name?

Comment: No, i thought it was called this way

Comment: Add a picture of the other side- there may be some text on it.
The "touchpad" is resistive IMHO - I guess that there is a button for it.